# How to resize mat-button with svg mat-icon

Tags: html, css, angular

I have PrimeNg and Angular Materials buttons on the same td. I am trying to resize my mat-buttons to match size with my pButtons but they will not change properly.
Should I be using a different type of button with my icon?

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kt9U4.png]

**HTML**

```
<button mat-mini-fab class="identify_icon"(click)="zebraIdentify()"><mat-icon svgIcon="identify_icon"></mat-icon> </button>
<button mat-mini-fab class="start_icon" (click)="zebraStartReads()"><mat-icon svgIcon="start_icon"></mat-icon> </button>
<button mat-mini-fab class="stop_icon" (click)="zebraStopReads()"><mat-icon svgIcon="stop_icon"></mat-icon> </button>
```

**CSS**

```
::ng-deep .mat-mini-fab {
height:3px !important;
padding-bottom: 40px !important;
border-radius: 9px !important;
/* font-size: 1em; */
transition: none !important;
box-shadow: none !important;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-left: 5px;
}

.identify_icon {
    background-color: #59BFC9;
}

.start_icon {
    background-color: #A2CB75;
}

.stop_icon {
    background-color: #E01515;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `transform: scale(2);` style for svg element you want to resize, where 2 is 200% of actual size:

```
.size-24 button svg {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Kavinda that really helped!